# What font (with math support) is this (picture)?

Tags: fonts

I've seen this font several times (in Springer books for instance) and would like to use it in my documents if possible. I've tried What The Font to no avail. Can anyone give me some pointers on what it is and how to use it with pdfLaTeX?

[image]

(picture taken from http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387972862#aboutBook)

Comment: Surely it's Computer Modern? Which is the default?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is Computer Modern, the standard font used by LaTeX. You just type in the text without any special font package.

Comment: Well, this is embarassing. For some reason it looks very different to me when I see it in print. I'm very sorry for the bother.

Comment: @Au101 Book's copyright is from 1991. Hence we may assume that the advanced printer had not more than 300 dpi. This makes the glyphs bolder than nowadays.

Comment: Absolutely nothing to be sorry about and welcome to the site! :) For me, it was just that you made me doubt myself :P